# Bootstrap Datatables Javascript - Lengthmenu option not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have a bootstrap datatables searchable table that's working great, other than my inability to let users select how many rows they see per page. Right now, it's defaulting to just 10 results per page.  For simplicity, I've only included 3 rows, but I'd like to know what I am doing wrong for why the menu isn't showing to let users select the number of results per page.  Alternatively, if it's easier to just set it at 50, I would do that.  Either way, 10 isn't cutting it.

I made my best attempt to add  **"lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ]** per the Datatables documentation, but I am clearly missing something.

Bottom line: I need either (1) the menu to work for selecting the number of results per page or (2) be able to select 50 for the number of results per page instead of the default 10.

```
<head>

<title>Project Search</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel"=stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Modal -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


</div><div class="w3-content" style="max-width:2000px;margin-top:46px"><h1>Access Project Search<p><p></h1>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      "lengthMenu": [ 10, 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [ ],
        "visible": false,
        "searchable": false
    },
    {
        "targets": [  ],
        "visible": false
    }
],

        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
  columns: ':visible',
  format: {
    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
      var text = node.textContent;
      return column === 10 ? text.replace( /Open$/, '' ).trim() : data;
    }
  }
}
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
  columns: ':visible',
  format: {
    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
      var text = node.textContent;
      return column === 10 ? text.replace( /Open$/, '' ).trim() : data;
    }
  }
}
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
  columns: ':visible',
  format: {
    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
      var text = node.textContent;
      return column === 10 ? text.replace( /Open$/, '' ).trim() : data;
    }
  }
}
            },


            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                exportOptions: {
  columns: ':visible',
  format: {
    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
      var text = node.textContent;
      return column === 10 ? text.replace( /Open$/, '' ).trim() : data;
    }
  }
}
            },

            'colvis'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>

<style>

td.none {
  display: none;
}


</style>



<style>
.modal {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}
</style>
<style>
  .display.dataTable  {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
<style>
div.dt-button-collection {
    width: 215px;
}
</style>



<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The known name of the project." >Project Name</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The provided unique ID that distinguishes projects.">Project Number</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The conclusing time point of a project, which is sometimes, but not always the point at which funding ends.">End Date</th>
      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The primary funder of the project.">Funder</th>

      <th class="all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="A brief description on the scope and aims of a project.">Abstract</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>

        <td>Project 1</td>

        <td>P-1</td>

        <td>2018-04-30 00:00:00</td>

        <td>NIH</td>

        <td><div id="ex83"class="modal">
  <p>

  Abstract 1  <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#ex83" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p></td></tr>
  <tr>

        <td>Project 2</td>

        <td>P-2</td>

        <td>2024-03-31 00:00:00</td>

        <td>NIH</td>

        <td><div id="ex103"class="modal">
  <p>

  Abstract 2  <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#ex103" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p></td></tr>
  <tr>

        <td>Project 3</td>

        <td>P-3</td>

        <td>2021-01-31 00:00:00</td>

        <td>NIH</td>

        <td><div id="ex111"class="modal">
  <p> Abstract 3</p>
  <a href="#" rel="modal:close"></a>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#ex111" rel="modal:open"><button class="button">Open<span></span></button></a></p></td></tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your `dom: 'Bfrtip',` option. Add `l` (the letter l) to its list, or remove the `dom` option altogether if you don't need it - and just use the default layout.

See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) for details, explaining what all the letters mean.